# @JsonTypeInfo not adding "@class" id to json when wrapping class also has @JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to serialize a "holder" class that has a value in it whose type is derived from generics. ie "class HasValue" has a "private A value" inside it.

Additionally I've got and Interface "Inf" and a concrete class "InfCls" that implements that interface. The interface is marked with @JsonTypeInfo and told to create an "@class" field.

Everything works fine if the holder class doesn't have an @JsonTypeInfo on it. But when I add that it breaks.

NOTE: While I don't need the @JsonTypeInfo in this instance (since the holder is always a concrete class) the same issues arises when it is needed so I chose this as a simpler example.

SCWE below:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Objects;

import org.junit.Test;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo.As;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class SerializationIssues {

    // No @JsonTypeInfo on HasValue
    @Test
    public void json_HasValue_Inf_javaType() throws Exception {
        HasValue<Inf> object = new HasValue<>(new InfCls(1));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(HasValue.class, Inf.class);
        String serialized = objectMapper.writerFor(javaType).writeValueAsString(object);
        HasValue<?> deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(serialized, javaType);

        assertEquals(object, deserialized);
    }

    // @JsonTypeInfo on HasValueId
    @Test
    public void json_HasValueId_Inf_javaType() throws Exception {
        HasValueId<Inf> object = new HasValueId<>(new InfCls(1));

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(HasValueId.class, Inf.class);
        String serialized = objectMapper.writerFor(javaType).writeValueAsString(object);
        HasValueId<?> deserialized = objectMapper.readValue(serialized, javaType);

        assertEquals(object, deserialized);
    }

    // ===== An interface and impl to test @JsonTypeInfo =====
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    public static interface Inf {
    }

    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    public static class InfCls implements Inf {
        private int val;

        @JsonCreator
        public InfCls(@JsonProperty("val") int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "InfCls [val=" + val + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * 1 + val;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            InfCls other = (InfCls) obj;
            if (val != other.val)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    // ===== A class that has a value =====
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    public static class HasValue<A> {
        private final A val;

        @JsonCreator
        public HasValue(@JsonProperty("val") A val) {
            this.val = Objects.requireNonNull(val);
        }

        public A get() {
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "HasValue [val=" + val + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * 1 + ((val == null) ? 0 : val.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            HasValue<?> other = (HasValue<?>) obj;
            if (val == null) {
                if (other.val != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!val.equals(other.val))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY, isGetterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
    public static class HasValueId<A> {
        private final A val;

        @JsonCreator
        public HasValueId(@JsonProperty("val") A val) {
            this.val = Objects.requireNonNull(val);
        }

        public A get() {
            return val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "HasValue [val=" + val + "]";
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return 31 * 1 + ((val == null) ? 0 : val.hashCode());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            HasValueId<?> other = (HasValueId<?>) obj;
            if (val == null) {
                if (other.val != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!val.equals(other.val))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The serializer that you're bootstrapping with is being pushed out of the way as soon as the `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation is encountered, and the type info you provided it is being lost.

There are a couple of ways to fix this. You could provide explicit type infomation in the class:

```
public static class HasValueId<A extends Inf> {
    private final A val;
```

This would allow jackson to determine the field type through introspection and find your second annotation.

Or you could annotate the generic field with `@JsonTypeInfo`:

```
public static class HasValueId<A> {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
    private final A val;
```

...which would obviate the need for an annotation on the interface.

Once this is done you will no longer need to type your writer; plain old `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);` will work.

Comment: And this did indeed solve my problem. Thanks for the quick reply. 

Is there any general rule about when serializers are "pushed out"?

Comment: Sorry for the fuzzy terminology, but I've no idea what the official language is. If you look at `ObjectWriter.Prefetch.forRootType` you'll find the offending code. Once it finds a polymorphic type it "unwraps" the serializer, presumably to allow the dynamic typing to take precedence over the static.